# maven build from different repos from one pom.xml

Tags: maven

Is it possible to build(and not download) a dependency in same pom.xml?
Another team builds/maintains a code in git repo A. I have to use that as a library in my code.
When I build my code using maven, I want this to be checked out and built and then the jar be included as a dependency.

I understand this can be achieved using Jenkins jobs.
And in dev stage, I can install an already built jar in m2 repo and use the jar as dependency.

However, I would want to confirm if its possible to solve this scenario outside Jenkins. That is, I as a developer, can I configure the build of repo A during build my code?
I hope I am able to explain the scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: If the code is so tightly coupled that you want to build it every time, think about using a multi-module project in Maven, where one module is your code and one module is the code of the other project. Then you can have a parent pom that builds both modules and one can depend on the other.